# how do I find all documents with a field that is NaN in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nan

I want to delete all geospacial fields that are NaN so I can properly index my MongoDB.

How do I find all documents that have this though?

```
db.collection.find( { field: {$not: { $type: 1 } } })
```

won't work since NaN is of type Number.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
db.collection.find( { field: NaN })
```

actually works although I couldn't find any documentation on it

Comment: I do not see this as possible. `db.collection.find({ field: 0/0 })` would actually match something that was possibly inserted as `Nan` but otherwise it will just not serialize to valid BSON. I Don't think this Q&A is valid when it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: I don't understand your point, could you explain more please.

Comment: Is there any pymongo version of this query ?

Comment: @MayankJaiswal check my answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Solution for PyMongo:

```py
# If you're alright with numpy as a dependency
import numpy as np
db.collection.find({ 'field': np.nan })
```

or

```py
db.collection.find({ 'field': float('nan') })
```

FYI: I ran into this issue because `mongoexport` (mongo 3.0.7) wrote `NaN` into the JSON files it created.  [This appears to have been addressed in 3.3.5](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/c41841daa377747524a6050fa35fabd83c8f37e9).

So again using PyMongo and in a similar boat, you can replace `NaN` with Python's `None`, which `mongoexport` will convert to JSON valid `null`:

```py
import numpy as np
for doc in list(db.collection.find({ 'field': np.nan }))
    update_one({'_id': ObjectId(doc['_id'])},
                {'$set': {'field': (lambda x: None if np.isnan(x) else x)(doc['field'])}})
```