# Find all records with field data type which is not NaN

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I would like to find exactly the opposite to this question [how do I find all documents with a field that is NaN in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23907503/how-do-i-find-all-documents-with-a-field-that-is-nan-in-mongodb).

The keyword `$not` required a document, and I had success with `type`., guessing that NaN would be a double:

```
db.collection.find({'key2': {$not : {$type :1}}})
```

Another way I managed to find was using `$nin`:

```
db.collection.find({'key1': NaN,  'key2' : { $nin : [NaN]}}}))
```

Is there a better way? Can you point it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#op._S_ne) operator to find docs where a field doesn't contain a particular value.  Using `$ne` with `NaN` works fine in the shell:

```
db.collection.find({key1: {$ne: NaN}})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, congrats on doing this to your data. But the simple case here is build an expression that also comes out as `NaN` ( Within JavaScript of course ) and use that in your query filter.

Such as:

```js
db.collection.find({'key1': parseInt("a"),  'key2' : { $nin : [parseInt("a")] } } )
```

As the `parseInt()` on something that is *"Not a Number"* will produce the constant result and therefore meet the match conditions of the query.

Anywhere else, the `NaN` will evaluate as a "Double" or BSON type 1 and you would need other logic to distinguish that "type" from other possible "Double" values.